# Pass a value from ObjC code to a library file via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c

In my project, I am reading a set of data from an .hsp file via the following code:

```
-(void)readingFile:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *value ;

    if([str isEqual:@"1"]){
        value =@"n";

    }else if([str isEqual:@"2"]){
        value =@"a";

    }else if([str isEqual:@"3"]){
        value =@"c";
        }
    NSLog(@"%@",value);

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:value ofType:@"hsp"];
    NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r\n"]];
    for (NSString* line in lines) {
        if (line.length) {
            NSLog(@"line: %@", line);
        }
    }

}
```

The data look like this:

```
c vo val 13

c he val 0

c rr val 0.2

c ccs val 0.10

c rr val 0.54

c cc val 9

c rr val 10.75
```

On `onclick` of a radio button in my HTML page, I have to pass the above values to the library file, which is within the project itself.

This is the JS I am using in the HTML page:

```
function callToXcode(p1)
            {

                window.location ="call?cmd=getDetails&param1="+p1;
                //alert(p1);
            }
```

so how to pass the values to the library which is within the project from the objective C.

Comment: You haven't actually stated the problem.

Comment: Hi Josh Caswell i have edited the Question again with mentioning the problem clearly.

Comment: No, sorry, you haven't. In the Title your are asking how to pass values ObjC->Javascript. But in your question all is about reading files and about passing values Javascript->ObjC. Please explicitly state what you want to pass to javascript, and show the javascript code, that should consume the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 answer.

If you want to pass value from one library to another and don't know how, the most easy way is save the data in a file with one language and when the other will use, it read the file.

If you are using a UIWebView and want to read the value of the Java Script in the page, this can be done using this function:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;
```

Than, you can use a lot of strategic to connect the Java Script and Objective-c. This code read the content of 2 text box:

```
NSString *code = 
      @"var value =  document.getElementsByName('textbox1')[0].value + \";\" + "
       "             document.getElementsByName('textbox2')[0].value;\n"
       " value \n";  //Just read the variable value to send it out
NSString *result = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:code];
```

This will create a string with: `text1;text2`. Than you can do what you want with this.